# DNS not resolving on same network only from outside - 3 days of headache already

Tags: server, dns, iptables

I have a domain forwarded to my apache server let's say test.example.com.
This works fine outside my home network I can reach it via mobile (4G).

But on my laptop I can't reach it. Also I can't reach it when I enable WiFi on my phone. I do have played with iptables, dnsmasq (disabled now) and dnsresolv. Added static network interface.

**iptables**

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports mdns
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports 4000

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

**dns resolv.conf**

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

**network interface**

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 192.168.2.14
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 192.168.2.254
        dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

Someone any idea why this problem is happening?

**EDIT**

Things getting more strange! When I add the domain in my hosts file on laptop and add the servers internal IP (192.168.2.14) it can resolve it. Weird.

Starting to think it's somehow my own laptop and not the server.

Please help!

Thanks!

Comment: Hi There!! Where is your apache server located? Were you able to connect from your laptop outside?? Is your apache server and network you use to connect are on the same subnet??... please add more detail to assist better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the late reply and thanks for the help, but I have found my issue.

Apparently my server was under DoS attack, luckily only a few ip's.
Somehow this only affected machines inside the home network and not directly the server it self, because I was able to access it from outside my home network.

I've blocked them using ufw firewall and it seems I'm able to access my server now.

If someone has a better answer to prevent this, please let me know.